# How to find color scheme of a website

Tags: css

I like this website's color scheme, http://flat.io. I will like to use its color scheme for my website. How could I find it? I tried viewing the source code but couldn't find the information.

Comment: Try using developer tools in chrome or just press F12 and inspect the code.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a question that is well suited to StackOverflow. There is no code, only an external link and the actual question is vague at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inspect in chrome(F12).
  For the website ,you provided: This is the color scheme.

```
 background: linear-gradient(45deg,#33b1f8 37%,#6e90f6 100%);
```

You can follow the google devTools for Live-edit ,changes will be reflected in UI.
Live-edit style property names and values in the Styles pane. All styles are editable, except the ones that are greyed out (as is the case with user agent stylesheets).

To edit a name or value, click on it, make your changes, and press Tab or Enter to save the change.

Follows this:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Hope it helps.!

Answer (score 0):

They used the CSS property linear-gradient to apply that color scheme.

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg,#33b1f8 37%,#6e90f6 100%);
```

That is what you are looking for.

Next time read the guidlines for posting a question. :)

Comment: Thanks. How did you find the color codes (so that I could do it myself next time)?

Comment: When you do F12 to inspect the code, in the elements tab, to your right you find styles tab,where you can find the css applied.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the colors is easy. Find a color picker and choose the colors from either side. You can use photoshop as well.

**Left**

```
HTML code:  #36B1F7
RGB code:   R: 54 G: 177 B: 247
```

**Right**

```
HTML code:  #6297F7
RGB code:   R: 98 G: 151 B: 247
```

[image]

But from that site the best way is to use the browser inspector and click the `style` tab. That is because it has a degree angle. Here you can find,

[image]

```
linear-gradient(45deg,#33b1f8 37%,#6e90f6 100%)
```

Mentioned by *Yashwanth M*

Comment: Thank you! I used ExtensionColorPick Eyedropper extension for Chrome to pick the colors. However, I accepted Kishor's answer as he provided the link which I could read to understand how to inspect elements.

Comment: @ManuChadha no worries.